# Why is there no playorm support for play 2.x

Tags: playframework, playorm

I notice that speed considerations have been mentioned on the playorm github page, but are there any technical limitations that stop this from being implemented?

Are there any projects under way to add 2.x support?

I would prefer not to have to write this myself if there is already a solution out there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no solution.  play 2.x is very slow....compiling, changes to html requiring a recompile and it has been extremely frustrating for those coming from the 1.x world.  Many from 1.x tried to go to 2.x and even one of my clients wrote in 2.x to start with has now backported to play1.x due to such a huge productivity lost(and I love scala too but the cycle of productivity is just much slower in 2.x).

That is why we did 1.x first.  We currently do not have support for 2.x at this time though.  PLEASE file an issue on github as we were waiting until we saw users that requested it...our first user that wanted play integration was a 1.x guy as well AND we use play 1.x instead as well.

**So, file an issue and do you use scala 2.x or java 2.x?**  (I mean your code will be in scala or in java?).

Also, playORM has tighter integration as annotations are rescanned on play1.x restart and in play2.x we would plan on keeping that there as well.

thanks,
Dean

Comment: Thanks, I have created the issue

Comment: Support for Play2.x is now added in Playorm.